# Not Able to create Sandbox test user on ebay

Tags: ebay-api

Normally, the sandbox account can be created using Sandbox Registration Tool, when you are logged into: developer.ebay.com.

(Direct url - http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/sandboxuser.asp )

When i am creating test user its giving error like "Sandbox User Not Created. Userid is too vulgar"

I am entering correct user name and  email.

Can anyone suggest how can i registered test user ?  or can anyone suggest where can i see list of test user in developer account in ebay.

Comment: Try a different email address/name. It sounds from the error like it is triggering a validation error.

Comment: yes , i have tried with new email address also but at this time when i am click on Create user then nothing happen and just page refreshed. No Messages displayed :(

Comment: I'm not sure then. Maybe it's a genuine bug. You could check the javascript console to see if there are any errors or try contacting Ebay directly for help.

Answer (score -3):

You Can Solve Your All Registration/Login Problem From Here:

visit : http://pages.sandbox.ebay.com/

and try to register/login

For Creating SandBox User follow this link: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/sandboxuser/